# I want to get the host MAC address in kubernetes pod where that pod runing on

Tags: kubernetes

I want to get the MAC address of the host in the POD, the POD network doesn't use hostnetwork. I found that the node UID's suffix is the host' MAC address and I want to find the source where this UID value get from?

The suffix of uid (525400a9edd3) is the MAC address(ether 52:54:00:a9:ed:d3) of that host?

```
kubectl get nodes node1 -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
...
  uid: 96557f0f-fea6-11e8-b826-525400a9edd3
...
```

```
ifconfig eth0
        eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.68.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fea9:edd3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:a9:ed:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Could you help me to find how node uid is created accros the source code?

I want to know the host MAC address in kubernetes pod where that pod runing on.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at any of the solutions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692258/find-mac-address-in-the-filesystem) to see where you can find the MAC address from your filesystem. Then you simply need to mount that file into your container using a [hostpath volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), and read the info from there.

Comment: @Frank Hopkins You are mounting a path that belongs to the node onto the container, so the information you see is the node information.

Comment: ah, I'm an idiot and overlooked the "hostpath volume" reference just reading "mount into your container". Thanks for the answer, sorry for the time theft ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pods are likely running within a node.

To get the node MAC address run arp NodeName on your controlplane node:

Start by getting the list of nodes and their names

```
kubectl get nodes -owide

root@controlplane:~# k get nodes -owide
NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
controlplane   Ready    control-plane,master   35m   v1.20.0   10.4.57.3     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   5.4.0-1057-gcp   docker://19.3.0
node01         Ready    <none>                 35m   v1.20.0   10.4.57.6     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   5.4.0-1057-gcp   docker://19.3.0
```

Run arp NODENAME (on the controlplane) to get the MAC address of the node you want. In this case, we are getting the MAC address for node01.

```
arp node01
```

Output

```
root@controlplane:~# arp node01
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.4.57.5                ether   02:42:0a:04:39:04   C                     eth0
```